# Query not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table 'A' with column 'col' with values:

a.b.1.c

a.b.2.c

a.b.26.d

If I execute this Select it works:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
A
WHERE col LIKE 'a.b.[2-9]%';
```

If I execute this one, it does'nt:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
A
WHERE col LIKE 'a.b.[2-9][0-9]*%';
```

The expected result of the query should be:

a.b.2.c

a.b.26.d

So, I need the "*" to be optional the second number

Why is this happening? How could I make it work to allow numbers greater than 9?

Here are both [fiddle1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/89f2c/1) [fiddle2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/89f2c/2):

Comment: `*` is the culprit in the second one.

Comment: the * in your second query is the problem. Why is it there

Comment: if the `[0-9]` is optional and you require the results to include `a.b.2.c`, then what's wrong with your first statement ?
Just curious to know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- not needed. Try this;

  ```
  select * from a
  WHERE col LIKE 'a.b.[2-9][0-9]%' or col like 'a.b.[2-9]%'
  ```

Comment: But I need it to be optional, it should also return me the a.b.2.c

Answer (score 2):

Try without `*` and use  `or` operator

```
SELECT
*
FROM
A
WHERE col LIKE 'a.b.[2-9]%' or col LIKE 'a.b.[2-9][0-9]%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (without *):

```
SELECT
*
FROM
A
WHERE col LIKE 'a.b.[2-9][0-9]%';
```

Comment: But I need it to be optional, it should also return me the a.b.2.c

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE col LIKE 'a.b.[2-9][0*-9]%';
```